# Block DHCP ports between two routers

Tags: dhcp, bridge

I have two building networks connected with a wireless bridge. Both on the same subnet, but both have there own router, gateway, internet, etc. My old wireless bridge had a firewall, so I could block ports 67 and 68 from there to keep dhcp from crossing. That's been working extremely well for about 10 years. However, I had to get a new wireless bridge and it no longer has firewall capabilities. Is there an easy way to block these ports from the router or do I need to maybe buy a second router to act as a firewall right before the wireless bridge..... I'm running all Ubiquiti routers and bridges with a managed netgear prosafe switch. I don't see any firewall options on that switch though.
Thanks

Comment: They way you do this with Ubiquiti hardware is to purchase a Ubiquiti Gateway Pro

Comment: I have a dream machine pro on one side and an edgerouter 4 on the other. I think a Gateway Pro is more for WAN side firewall blocking I think? Was really hoping there was still a cheaper/easier option just to block two ports through one LAN side ethernet cable =) Kicking myself that I didn't realize this bridge had no firewall rules till I had it set up, because that was a super easy way...

Comment: So purchase a cheaper option there isn’t any reason another firewall brand wouldn’t work just not as “simple” as joining Ubiquiti hardware to the network. I am extremely confused why your trying to disable DHCP by blocking the port instead of just disabling the service on part of the network.

Comment: *I am extremely confused why your trying to disable DHCP by blocking the port instead of just disabling the service on part of the network.* My thoughts exactly.

Comment: two completely different networks with there own internet. They both share resources though on the LAN side so it works well to have them both there own dhcp servers/set of IP's that keep them connected to there own gateway while letting them both act as one big simple network. If I disabled one dhcp, then they would all just connect to that internet. I know there's more complicated ways to do this, but this is simple and has worked really well. Only issue is blocking 67 and 68 so they don't cross....

Comment: I think it would help if you drew a picture of your network. if they are two completely different networks, then 1) there is no issue with DHCP crossing the boundrary because its a different broadcast domain, and 2) there is a router between them to let them talk to each other, which is a fine place to firewall. clearly there is a misunderstanding here.

Comment: Thanks Frank. you are correct. two completely different networks. One routers gateway is set at 0.1 the other at 192.168.0.2. They are basically connected with a wireless ethernet cable. Even without a firewall between the two, it works fine if I have enough spaces allotted for both the dhcp ranges. Just less control on who goes where. Was just checking for ideas, but I understand it can be lost in translation =). Think I'll just put a cheap router in between the two and block the ports from there. Unless any other thoughts, let me know if I should kill this question or make an answer. Thanks